# Configuring a mysql table or query to meet these needs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have gotten the gist of most of mysql query and how to set-up my table however I am a little lost on how I can do this.

I currently have a table that has this format:

```
 tag_target_id | tag_id   | sub_tag_id | tag_target_name | tag_type_id
    int(11)    | int(11)  | int(11)    |   varchar(255)  | int(11
    <PK>       | <FK>     |   <FK>     |                 | <FK>
```

A single `tag_target_id` corresponds to one piece of content ie. a video, article etc. now in the table there should be multiple entries with the same `tag_target_id and tag_target_name` and different `tag_id , sub_tag_id , tag_type_id` simple enough

So my problem is when I am inserting data into the table I have a PDO query that looked like this:

```
 "INSERT INTO phpro_tag_targets (tag_id, sub_tag_id, tag_target_name, tag_type_id) 
  VALUES (:tag_id, :sub_tag_id,:tag_target_name,:tag_type_id)"
```

... I used to have `tag_target_id` as auto increment however each new query obviously incremented the `tag_target_id` so a single piece of content would have `tag-target_id = 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` for eg. where I would like to have each piece of new content have one single `tag_target_id`
Now I would like to somehow have each new piece of content have a new `tag_target_id` but not each entry into the table for a single piece of content have it's own unique idea

so for eg. for one piece of content in the table  all data for that content could look like this:

```
 tag_target_id | tag_id   | sub_tag_id | tag_target_name | tag_type_id
    int(11)    | int(11)  | int(11)    |   varchar(255)  | int(11
     54        |  22      |    64      | url_to_content  |   16     
     54        |  66      |    82      | url_to_content  |   24
     54        |  22      |    77      | url_to_content  |   18 
     54        |  87      |    55      | url_to_content  |   16
     54        |  66      |    92      | url_to_content  |   20
```

So how can I change the structure of the table or write a query set to achieve this desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that You have separate table with info about content itself You may create a [composite primary key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on fields `tag_target_id`, `tag_id` and `sub_tag_id`.

And make `tag_target_id` as FK for this content table.

For existing table the query will be

```
ALTER TABLE phpro_tag_targets ADD PRIMARY KEY uniq_target_tag_sub (tag_target_id,tag_id,sub_tag_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you still need a unique id to distinguish the records. I would create a new column called something like "tag_content_id" and use that to store the grouping id (in your example 54). This way your table will have a unique id to use for the key (tag_target_id) and also a way to distinguish between different content entries and group items together (tag_content_id). When all else fails, add a column!

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice ... If I have no real need for `tag_target_id` to be a <PK> Ie there is no real need for it be unique can I just use that? Either way is there a simple way to ensure when inserting a new piece of content that the `tag_content_id` or `tag_target_id` does not already exist in the table? this is my real problem (sorry if I left that unclear)

Comment: you can set the column to be unique and then it won't accept duplicates and will fire off an error. or you can just execute a select statement to see if the record exists before you insert it.